# Cannot convert return expression of type 'User' to return type 'User?'

Tags: swift

I have this error:

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'User' to return type 'User?'

```
    var CURRENT_USER: User? {
        if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
           return currentUser
        }
        return nil
    }
```

`User` declaration:

```
class User {
    var email: String?
    var ProfileImageUr: String?
    var username: String?
    var id: String?
}

extension User {

    static func transForUser(dict: [String: Any], key: String) -> User {

        let user = User()
        user.email = dict["email"] as? String
        user.ProfileImageUr = dict["ProfileImageUr"] as? String
        user.username =  dict["username"] as? String
        user.id = key

        return user
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you have `User` declared twice. There are probably two different classes, both called `User`.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this you return unwrapped User.

Try

```
return Auth.auth().currentUser
```

instead of

```
if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
           return currentUser
}
return nil
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but not working i show this error again // Cannot convert return expression of type 'User?' to return type 'User?'

Answer (score 0):

There are two different classes, both called User.

- one you created and the other one is from FirebaseAuth.

The solution just renames your class to another name.

Comment: I am running across your post now, can we not create a User class because it's already declared by firebase?